# CTC loss crashes during NN training. Wrong label generation? tf.cast(tf.equal(y_true, y_pred), backend.floatx())

Tags: tensorflow, loss-function

I am training a neural network for RNA sequence basecalling using nanopore signal.
my input of the neural network is [None,400,1] and generate an output [None,400,5], where 5 are
my labels including the blank value. my output can vary in length for the training.

For example, if i have two raw signal of 400 time points, they generate two sequence "CUCA" and "CCAUGA". How i should generate my CTC loss label for matching these two informations (input constants and variable output)? There is a way to let the CTC loss manage variable output during trainig?

To resolve the problem, I am using the following CTC loss:

def CTCLoss_v1(y_true, y_pred):

```
epsilon = backend_config.epsilon
y_true = tf.cast(y_true, dtype=tf.int32)

# Create a sparse label from a dense tensor y_true
sparse_labels = tf.sparse.from_dense(y_true)

batch_len = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_pred)[0], dtype="int32")

#label_length =tf.math.count_nonzero(y_true, axis=-1, dtype="int32")  #tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[1], dtype="int32")
label_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[1], dtype="int32") # time frames
label_length = label_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len,), dtype="int32")

logit_length = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_pred)[1], dtype="int32") # time frames
logit_length = logit_length * tf.ones(shape=(batch_len,), dtype="int32")

y_pred = tf.math.log(
    tf.compat.v1.transpose(y_pred, perm=[1, 0, 2]) + epsilon()
)

ctc_loss_value = tf.nn.ctc_loss(
    labels=sparse_labels,
    logits=y_pred,
    label_length=label_length,
    logit_length=logit_length,
    logits_time_major=True,
    blank_index= 0)

return ctc_loss_value
```

for the labels i am using [0,1,2,3,4] for the vocabulary ["blank",A,C,U,G]. Now, if i have for example sequence ACCUG i am generating the label like this [0,1,0,2,0,2,0,3,0,4,0]. to notice that my label_length is 40. but when i try to run the neural network it gives me the following erorr:

```
  matches = tf.cast(tf.equal(y_true, y_pred), backend.floatx())
```

Node: 'Equal'
required broadcastable shapes
[[{{node Equal}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_67658]

thank you in advance for your attention and help!